# How to install pip packages with Dockerfile? Getting permission restrictions error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, rasa

I have the following Dockerfile that I use to deploy an Rasa Bot app on Google's App Engine:

```
FROM rasa/rasa
ENV BOT_ENV=development
COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN pip install rasa phonenumbers pgeocode
#ENTRYPOINT ["rasa", "run", "-vv", "--enable-api", "actions"]
ENTRYPOINT ["rasa", "run", "-vv", "--enable-api", "--endpoints", "endpoints.yml", "--credentials", "credentials.yml", "-p", "8080"]
```

But the deployment fails to install the `phonenumbers` and `pgeocode` packages, somehow doesn't have problem with rasa.

The error I get is this:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/build/lib/python3.6/site-packages/phonenumbers'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

The command '/bin/sh -c pip install rasa phonenumbers pgeocode' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I have tried using the `--user` as suggested, and in some other questions I saw answers suggesting using `sudo` with `-H` flag, but that as well fails, with a different error saying that `sudo` is not recognized.

If I remove those 2 failing packages, my app runs, except that it can't perform some actions for which those packages are needed.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the failure message when you use `--user`.

Comment: I don't think `sudo` is installed by default on debian, which is what this image is using. You could try installing it. You might also want to try adding `USER 0` to the dockerfile, which indicates to use the root user, which should have full permissions.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/71753536/5820158 (it *might* be that the user your running the install commands as has no `/home/<user>` directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `rasa/rasa` base image, this is why `rasa` is either already installed or installs successfully.

The [documentation for this image](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/how-to-deploy/#adding-custom-dependencies) suggests using the `--no-cache-dir` flag:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

You can also try running your `Dockerfile` commands as the root user by doing:

```
FROM rasa/rasa
USER root
```

Comment: I tried with the first suggestion but got the same error. Adding `USER root` fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

USER root worked for me too. For future ppl, don't forget to set USER back as per
http://redhatgov.io/workshops/security_containers/exercise1.2/

i.e:
USER root
...
USER 1001 (or whatever user you want)