# How to deal with Permission Errors with Pip inside a Docker-compose container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

I've been trying to run a container for a python project, and part of this is having to use pip from time to time inside the container. When I do this I end up getting two different errors when I try to `pip install`:

```
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
```

and

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
Check the permissions.
```

So far I have tried the following solutions:

- running `pip` with the `--user` option
- running docker-compose as a root user, which is not an option because the files it creates are then owned by root

Here's my docker-compose and dockerfile:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./services/backend
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./services/backend:/app
    user: 1000:1000
    command: uvicorn src.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

```
FROM python:3.10
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My file structure is this:

```
repository
├── docker-compose.yml
└── services
    └── backend
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── requirements.txt
        └── src
            └── main.py
```

So is it possible to have the container have access to '.local', so that I can run pip install inside the container, or is it just better to keep all pip installs to when the container is being built?

Comment: I suppose `pip install` inside Dockerfile successfully runs under `root` user. In Composefile however you set the user to `1000` so when running `pip install` inside the container it runs under different user, which does not work. Is it possible to run `sudo pip install` inside the container?

Moreover, where does the user `1000` come from? If you run `cat /etc/passwd` inside the Python container you will see there is no such user. If you need to run Python app under different user you should first create him in Dockerfile with `RUN useradd...`.

Comment: I wouldn't `pip install` inside a running container; as soon as the container is destroyed, that work will be lost.  Can you run `pip freeze` in the Python virtual environment where you normally work to regenerate the `requirements.txt` file, then `docker-compose build` a new image?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the problem is that your user (`1000:1000`) is **missing it's home directory**, which is where pip will try to install.

To solve this you can create the user explicitly:

Dockerfile

```
# User root user to create a non-root user so we can install pip packages without root
USER root

# (fyi) You can pass args from docker-compose.yml, just remove the "=myuser" from here
ARG USERNAME=myuser

# for whatever reason the /home/username directory is not created with useradd  for me :/
# RUN useradd -u ${USER_UID} --gid ${USER_GID} ${USERNAME}
RUN adduser --uid 1000 --disabled-password ${USERNAME}

# Switch to our non-root user
USER ${USERNAME}
# add the default pip bin install location to the PATH
ENV PATH="$PATH:/home/${USERNAME}/.local/bin"

# Run your pip install commands
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
# you can remove the "user: 1000:1000" from here as we set it in the dockerfile
# user 1000:1000
```